# ECS container exit code 2

Tags: amazon-ecs

i am creating an ECS cluster with docker image library/wordpress:latest and i get the desired task in running state but when i build this image using following Dockerfile and push it to my dockerhub repo and then try to create this cluster using my new image the containers fails by giving Exit code 2
Could you please suggest me what am i doing wrong here?

```
#Base image
FROM wordpress:latest
LABEL version="latest" maintainer="xxxxxxx <xxxxxx>"

# Update apt
RUN apt-get update

# Add a user for running applications.
RUN useradd apps
RUN mkdir -p /home/apps && chown apps:apps /home/apps

## for apt to be noninteractive
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN true

# Install all necessary packages
RUN apt-get -y install build-essential libpoppler-cpp-dev pkg-config x11vnc xvfb fluxbox wget wmctrl gnupg2 unzip zip

# Set the Chrome repo.
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list

# Install Chrome.
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install google-chrome-stable

# Install Chrome driver
RUN wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/94.0.4606.61/chromedriver_linux64.zip \
    && unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip \
    && mv chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver \
    && chown root:root /usr/bin/chromedriver \
    && chmod +x /usr/bin/chromedriver

# create folder to store requirements.txt file
RUN mkdir /home/automation
RUN mkdir /home/automation/FrontEnd
WORKDIR /home/automation

# Copy config and scripts
COPY requirements.txt ./requirements.txt
COPY TestSuites /home/automation/FrontEnd/TestSuites
COPY Resources /home/automation/FrontEnd/Resources
COPY TestRunner.py /home/automation/FrontEnd
COPY TestRail/ /home/automation/TestRail
COPY run-frontend-tests.sh /home/automation/run-tests.sh
COPY FrontEndResultParser.py /home/automation/FrontEnd/FrontEndResultParser.py

# Install python 3.9 and pip3
RUN apt-get -y install python3-dev python3.9 python3-pip

# Install dependencies
RUN pip install "setuptools==58.0.0"
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["sh", "run-tests.sh"]
```

i am basically just trying to run a script into the container

I used a worpress image and built my own image out of it, thought it would keep the container up and my script will be executed but that didnt happen. My ECS cluster didnt have any running task, all i saw iin the events was service stage-fe-auto has started 1 tasks: task e83587e734c94f77. and when i opened the task details, it had Exit Code 2 and Working directory /home/app but in my Dockerfile my work directory is differen. Not sure what i did wrong